# If statement multiple choice c#

Tags: c#, .net

string question1;

```cs
//Question 1
WriteLine("What is his favourite sport? ");
WriteLine("a) Soccer");
WriteLine("b) Basketball ");
WriteLine("c) Tennis ");
WriteLine("d) Football " );
Write("your answer is: ");
question1 = ReadLine();

if (question1 != "a" || question1 != "b" || question1 != "c")
    Write("That is incorrect try again");
else
    Write("that is correct");
```

No matter what letter I put it always gives me an incorrect try again, what am I doing wrong? Also would a while loop be better when trying to create a quiz game?

Comment: while the answer is d

Answer (score 3):

Those "or" (`||`) operators should almost certainly be "and" (`&&`) operators.

Think of what happens when you enter `c`, for example. Obviously, that *will* be `c` but it *won't* be `a` or `b`, so two of the sub-conditions will be true.

In fact, that's the case no matter *which* of `a`, `b`, or `c` that you enter (if you enter something else, all *three* will be true). And since an `x || y || z` is true if *any* of its sub-components is true, the expression as a whole is always true. The following table hopefully illustrates this:

| Input | != "a" (A) | != "b" (B) | != "c" (C) | A or B or C |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| a | False | True | True | True |
| b | True | False | True | True |
| c | True | True | False | True |
| d | True | True | True | True |
| other | True | True | True | True |

In other words, unless `question1` is some sort of "Schrodinger's variable" that can be all of `a`, `b`, and `c` *at the same time,* that `if` statement of yours will *never* be false.

---

However, if the subject's favourite sport is football, I'm not sure why you wouldn't just use the much simpler condition below:

```cs
if (question1 == "d") {
    WriteLine("That is correct");
} else {
    WriteLine("That is incorrect try again");
}
```

That approach (accepting the right answer) seems far easier than what your original code seems to be doing (rejecting all of the the wrong answers).

---

And, yes, a `while` loop probably *would* be better for a quiz scenario, something like the following would be a good start.

I've even added a rudimentary scoring system, because I get bored easily :-)

The points for a question reduce if you answer wrongly: two points for a correct answer first time, one point if you get it right second time, no points otherwise:

```cs
int score = 0; // Done once before ALL questions.
int awardPoints;
string answer;

awardPoints = 2; // Done before EACH question.
do {
    // Output the question and get an answer.

    WriteLine();
    WriteLine("What is his favourite sport (x to exit)? ");
    WriteLine("  a) Soccer");
    WriteLine("  b) Basketball");
    WriteLine("  c) Tennis");
    WriteLine("  d) Football" );
    Write("Your answer: ");
    answer = ReadLine();

    // Evaluate answer (d is correct here). An x answer
    // will produce no output as it assumes you want to
    // just exit.

    if (answer == "d") {
        score += awardPoints;
        WriteLine("Correct, you earned {} points, now at {}",
            awardPoints, score);
    } else if (answer != "x") {
        // Incorrect answer. Halve question points so
        // user cannot simply keep trying without
        // some penalty.

        WriteLine("Incorrect, try again");
        awardPoints = awardPoints / 2;
    }
} while (answer != 'd' && answer != 'x');

// Here, either the correct answer or 'x' was
// given. If 'x', probably want to stop asking
// questions. Otherwise go on to next question.
```

Comment: Thank you so much, It helped  and thank you for explaining it to me rather then giving me the answer right away. I should have enclosed that I wouldnt want the answer but more of understanding it. But regardless thank you!

Comment: @Moose9000: I much prefer to educate people where possible, I may find myself having to maintain their code one day :-)

Comment: This definitely helped, I actually implemented an award base system as well,  But yours looks a lot cleaner and has helped me better understand it. Thank you so much for taking the time to show me the process, it means a lot.

Answer (score 2):

Please, try this way.

```
void Main()
{
    string question1 = "";

    do
    {
        //Question 1
        Console.WriteLine();
        Console.WriteLine();
        Console.WriteLine("What is his favourite sport? ");
        Console.WriteLine("a) Soccer");
        Console.WriteLine("b) Basketball ");
        Console.WriteLine("c) Tennis ");
        Console.WriteLine("d) Football ");
        Console.Write("your answer is: ");
        question1 = Console.ReadLine();
        Console.WriteLine(question1);

        if (question1 == "a" || question1 == "b" || question1 == "c")
        {
            Console.Write("That is incorrect try again");
        }
        else
        {
            Console.Write("that is correct");

        }
    } while (question1 != "q");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When you use `||` operator, as soon as any condition is true, it stops processing rest of the cases and marks the statement as true.

The best way is, to **test the correct answer** and put **rest** of the cases in **else** block 
and mark them as 'incorrect'

```
if (question1 == 'correctOption')
{
System.Console.Write("That is correct.");  
}
else
{
System.Console.Write("That is incorrect try again");  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The runtime evaluates from left to right. In case of `||` it stops at the first `true` and returns `true`. If there is nothing which is `true` then it returns `false`.

In case of `&&` it stop at the first `false` and returns `false`.

The readable code if to check for right answer and say correct and for all others display incorrect. This will also take care of user entering any other value other than "a","b,"c" as well like say "t"